# How do I get Animate CC to recognize drops in my drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, easeljs, animate-cc

I'm trying to build a drag and drop interaction in animate CC using a movie clip symbol. The goal is for it to animate when it's dropped in a drop area. I've seen, but haven't implemented a sprite sheet for that, but it seems like a good idea.

However, my question is more based on getting it to recognize a drop when it happens. I can't test the sprite sheet idea until I get this.
I've been looking at a bunch of tutorials like this one, [here](https://youtu.be/FrwKAikvims), which is just editing [this one](http://codepen.io/samualli/pen/xbVGpP) to handle symbols in Animate CC or other objects. It got me a good bit of the way, but it's not working out too well on drops. I can pick up the draggable just fine, but I can't get it to get off the mouse even when I release the mouse.

`dragger` is the symbol in animate that I'm trying to drag (just in case that wasn't obvious).

```
dragger.on("pressmove", function(evt){
    evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
    evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;
    stage.update(evt);
 });
```

This part is what's giving me trouble I think:

```
//refuses to release. doesn't recognize it.
dragger.on("pressup", function(evt){    
    //lock position of thermometer and play stabby animation
    dragger.x = dragger.x;
    dragger.y = dragger.y;

    if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, this.targetRight)){    //Intersection testing for good
        alert("YAY you're right AND it works!");

    }else if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, this.targetWrong)){   //intersection Testing for bad
        alert("BOO its wrong, but YAY it works");
    }
    stage.update(evt);
});
```

and then my code for intersect (for checking if it's over the drop area):

```
function intersect(obj1, obj2){ 
  var objBounds1 = obj1.getBounds().clone();
  var objBounds2 = obj2.nominalBounds.clone(); // <-----Changed this line

  var pt = obj1.globalToLocal(objBounds2.x, objBounds2.y);

  var h1 = -(objBounds1.height / 2 + objBounds2.height);
  var h2 = objBounds2.height / 2;
  var w1 = -(objBounds1.width / 2 + objBounds2.width);
  var w2 = objBounds2.width / 2;


  if(pt.x > w2 || pt.x < w1) return false;
  if(pt.y > h2 || pt.y < h1) return false;

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Any chance you can post the demo? Your code _looks_ fine, but it is hard to tell without seeing what else is going on.

Comment: Sure, Just give me a second to pull up a link for it

Comment: @Lanny I'll put the link here: http://apersonnamedmike.github.io/drag-n-drop-demo/
When you let go of the mouse, and it's over one of the blue squares on the chicken, it should give you one of the alerts included in the code, but it doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking out the demo included, and I get an immediate error when I start dragging (note I always have the "break on error" toggle set in Chrome when the inspector is open).

The issue is because the "pressup" handler is not scoped, so the `obj2` is undefined. If you don't pass a scope, the method is called in the global scope.

```
var objBounds2 = obj2.getBounds().clone(); // Error!
```

You can easily fix this by passing a scope to the `on()` method. This will ensure that `this` refers to the current scope.

```
dragger.on("pressup", function(evt){    //this function will be very custom, always
    //lock position of thermometer and play stabby animation
    dragger.x = dragger.x;
    dragger.y = dragger.y;

    if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, this.targetRight)){    //Intersection testing for good
        alert("YAY you're right AND it works!");

    }else if(intersect(evt.currentTarget, this.targetWrong)){   //intersection Testing for bad
        alert("BOO its wrong, but YAY it works");
    }
    stage.update(evt);

}, this); // <-------------------- Only thing I changed
```

I added a 3rd parameter to the `on()` method, to pass the scope. That should solve that error, and might even solve your problem.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, I think that helped, but now it's telling me specifically that geBounds() isn't working on obj2 because it's unspecified. I'm guessing its because when i get this.targetRight it isn't recognizing that as an instance in my project?

Comment: What is `targetRight`? If it is a shape, it may not have bounds.

Comment: Yeah, it's a shape turned into a movie clip. in the demo, it's one of the blue squares. targetWrong is the same deal

Comment: You can use `nominalBounds` and `frameBounds` on content exported from Flash/Animate, which provides the un-transformed size of the content.

Comment: Ok, so I think I've made some headway. It doesn't look like the 2nd object is getting passed correctly on the intersect function. I got the error that it couldn't use clone(), and so I removed that to see what it would do, and its just now telling me that obj2 is null, so it can't do anything with it.

Comment: Can you update your code, or provide a working sample?

Comment: Yes to both, I'll have them up in just a bit. :)

Comment: Ok, so I've been Playing with it, and nominalBounds gets rid of the error that it's undefined, but it doesn't work with the right dimensions on the correct area. It acts like it has a huge bounding box or something. Not sure what it is. but here's a new link for a demo: http://apersonnamedmike.github.io/drag-n-drop-demo-2/